# slider javascript error - reading style undefined

Tags: javascript

I am having an error regarding a slider and am unsure how to fix it, i tried all thing s i know, can someone shed some light please where i have gone wrong?

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
   showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }

   slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  }
```

```css
.home-container { 
margin: 0px auto; // center
width:100%; 
text-align:center; 
overflow:hidden;
background-size: contain;

} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .home-container {
        width:100%;
    }
    
    
}
.slideshow-container {
   width: auto;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
   
}

.mySlides {
  display:none;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: rgb(245,205,245);

  font-size: 30px;
  position: bottom;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
        
}


.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
    align-content: center;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="home-container">

        <div class="slider-container">
                  
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/Main1.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Bohemia Creative Quarter" ></a> 
            <div class="text">Bohemia Creative Quarter</div>
              
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/2111.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Painting" ></a>
              <div class="text">The Moth</div>
        </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/166.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Pottery"></a>
              <div class="text">The Mudworks</div>
        </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/Forage21.jpeg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Flower Image"></a>
              <div class="text">Forage and Fleur</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
           <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/6.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Fancy Dress" ></a>
            <div class="text">Teddy Tinkers</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/101.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Crystals" ></a>
            <div class="text">The Crystal Catalyst</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
         <a href="businesses.html"> 
            <img
              src="Media/slider/71.jpg" class="responsive-img"
              alt="Rings" ></a>
            <div class="text">Silver Swann</div>
            </div>
           </div> 
        
    
       </div>
```

I understand it is related to the display.block but as mentioned I am unsure how to fix this. I have been stuck with this error for days and it is becoming very frustrating

Comment: What is the error, exactly? Your snippet seems to run without issue

Comment: The only issue I see is if `slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"` runs when there are no `.mySlides` elements present. See the link at the top of your post for solutions

Comment: (uncaught TypeError: cannot read properties of undifined (readingstyle)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: it switched between them both and i cannot explain it, its driving me crazy haha

Comment: it is an automatic slider, with an external js as I wanted all to be on 1 external file, or can this not be the case for the slider? would it be best to have the script on the page under the html code?